# For what values of $n$ is $n^2+n+2$ a power of $2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Working on isometric paths in hypercubes, I came up with the following simple, yet (imo) interesting problem. For what natural numbers $n$ exists a natural number $t$ such that $n^2+n+2=2^t$? The first few terms are $n=0,1,2,5,90$, and these are all below one million. Does someone have any idea how to approach this problem? I basically only want to know whether there exist infinitely many $n$ or not (maybe even that 0, 1, 2, 5, and 90 are the only possible ones).

Thanks,

Sacha

Comment: Beyond ($n=1,t=2$), $t$ will always be odd, because $n^2 < n^2+n+2 < (n+1)^2$.

Comment: It is easily equivalent to a beautiful relation
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{t-1}2^j
$$

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That there are no more positive solutions was proved by Nagell, settling a conjecture of Ramanujan. The problem is discussed in [this paper,](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2323504?uid=3739400&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3737720&uid=4&sid=21101144751691) and in this [Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan-Nagell_equation)

To see that these solve the problem, a small preliminary transformation of your equation is useful. Rewrite it as $4n^2+4n+8=2^k$, and then as $(2n+1)^2+7=2^k$. We have arrived at the Ramanujan-Nagell equation.

Comment: Thanks! Reading the Wikipedia article, I just realized I forgot the simplest of all solutions: $n=0$.

Comment: @Sacha: And there area few negatives, which presumably you are not interested in. That's why in the answer I wrote there are no more positive.

Comment: Ah yep, thanks. I just rephrased the question accordingly.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : So basically there are only few solutions as in wikipedia article given right ?