# Solve $2^n=k^2+k+2$ for positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This problem came from my own research ( research for fun, not professional ). I was able to simplify a little and solve some special cases, but I need a help to get the general case which is

"Find all pairs $(n,k)$ of positive integers such that $2^n=k^2+k+2$."

Thank you.

PS: It will be enough to consider $n$ odd.

Comment: To start, $\;(n,k)=(1,1)\,,\,(3,2)\,,\,(5,5)\;$ ...

Comment: I know this solutions and some more. But I need all solutions...and if there are infinite solutions, a prove of that fact and some formula. By the way, $(1,1)$ is not a solution, should be $(2,1)$.

Comment: You "need" all the solutions? What research "for fun" is that, then? Give some ideas, feedback...

Comment: Apart from $(13,90)$, do you know any other solution?

Comment: $$ 2^n = k^2 + k + 2 \Rightarrow 2(2^{n-1} - 1) = k(k+1) $$

$$ \Rightarrow 2^{n-1} - 1 = \frac{k(k+1)}{2} = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k $$ 

that's not an answer you can found some pairs from here

Comment: $k^2+k=2^n-2=2(2^{n-1}-1)$ which is not divisible by $4$ for $n\ge2$

So, $k\not\equiv0,-1\pmod4$ for $n\ge2$

Again, $2^{n+2}=4k^2+4k+8=(2k+1)^2+7$

If $n=2m,$ we have $ (2^{m+1})^2-(2k+1)^2=7$ which is impossible $\implies n$ must be odd

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Slightly easier to show that $k^2 < k^2 + k + 2 < (k+1)^2 $ hence cannot be a square of the form $2^{2m}$.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer $(13,90)$ is the bigger solution I found.

Comment: Nice approach Jyrki Lahtonen.

Comment: There are only solutions for $n=1,2,3,5,13$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan–Nagell_equation. So no need to keep looking for an elementary proof...

Comment: @barto This is great! Thank you!

Comment: See also: [Solve the equation $x^2+x+2=2^y$ in positive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2499516) and [For what values of $n$ is $n^2+n+2$ a power of $2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/185458)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is always a solution to $$ 2^n = u^2 + u v + 2 v^2,  $$ mostly because there is always a (primitive, that is $\gcd(a,b)=1$) solution to $$ 2^n = a^2 + 7 b^2.  $$ once $n \geq 3.$ It is too much to expect that $v$ can frequently be taken to equal $1.$

Edit, April 2014: as pointed out in comment in 2013 by barto, the solutions are finite and known, see [Ramanujan-Nagell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation)

Comment: Indeed, in this case is expected that there are a finite number of solutions. The bigger I found is $(13,90)$, then would be nice to have a proof that this is the last solution.

Answer (score 3):

Well, we can use the quadratic formula:

$$k = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-4(2-2^n)}}{2}$$

So it would be all pairs $(n, k)$ such that $1-4(2-2^n) = 2^{n+2}-7$ is an odd square.

Comment: How would you continue to find all such pairs?

Comment: @CalvinLin Hmm, I'm not sure I can give you a clean, closed formula for finding all such pairs. Basically you'd just want to find integer values for $n = \log_2 \left[\frac{(2m+1)^2+7}{4}\right]$.

Answer (score 2):

Reporting on my findings. Let's work in the ring $O=\mathbb{Z}[(-1+\sqrt{-7})/2]$ of
the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$. This field is of interest here, because
$$
k^2+k+2=(k-u_1)(k-u_2),
$$
where $u_1=(-1+\sqrt{-7})/2$ and $u_2=(-1-\sqrt{-7})/2$.

The prime $2$ splits in $O$ into a product of two principale ideals, one generated by $u_1$ the other by $u_2$. The only units in this ring are $\pm1$. As $u_1u_2=2$ the equation can be written as
$$
u_1^nu_2^n=(k-u_1)(k-u_2).
$$
Because $(k-u_1)-(k-u_2)=\sqrt{-7}$ the ideals generated by $(k-u_1)$ and $(k-u_2)$ are coprime (they only have prime factors lying above $2$). Therefore we can conclude that
$$
k-u_1=\pm u_1^n
$$
or
$$
k-u_2=\pm u_1^n.
$$
It is very difficult for either of these equations to produce a rational integer $k$ as the answer. For that to happen either $u_1^n\pm u_1$ or $u_1^n\pm u_2$ has
to be real. In other words the imaginary part of $u_1^n$ has to be $\pm\sqrt7/2.$

We have, indeed,
$$
\begin{aligned}
u_1^2&=\frac{-3-i\sqrt7}2\\
u_1^3&=\frac{5-i\sqrt7}2\\
u_1^5&=\frac{-11-i\sqrt7}2\\
u_1^{13}&=\frac{181-i\sqrt7}2
\end{aligned}
$$
accounting for the solutions found by OP.

It takes more than a bit of luck to get such small imaginary parts in the power $u_1^n$. As $|u_1|=\sqrt2$ we have $|u_1^n|=2^{n/2}$. Therefore for success the argument $n\phi$ has to be very close to an integer multiple of $\pi$. Here $\phi=\arg u_1=\pi-\arctan\sqrt7$, and we see that $13\phi/\pi\approx 7.99535$.
I checked the fractional parts (rounded to closest integer) of $n\phi/\pi$ up to $n=2000$. Smaller distances do occur but for so large values of $n$ that the imaginary parts are still huge.

Comment: It does feel like this is just Will Jagy's answer in different words.