# Solve the equation $x^2+x+2=2^y$ in positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, integers

Let $x,y$ are positive integers. Solve the equation
$$x^2+x+2=2^y$$

#### My work so far:

$$(2x+1)^2 + 7 = 2^{y+2}$$
If $y$ is even, then $x=1,y=2$.

Comment: @mdave16 Apparently, that apporach could at most lead to $x\equiv 1\pmod{12}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, you're right, i'm going about this the wrong way (although there are more primes, and more conditions could be made, it would never be conclusive)

Comment: We would get something of the  form $m^2 + 7 = 2^n$, right? This is the Ramanujan-Nagell equation - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan-Nagell_equation I don't think this is easy to solve!

Comment: See also: [Solve $2^n=k^2+k+2$ for positive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/480769) and [For what values of $n$ is $n^2+n+2$ a power of $2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/185458).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions are (brute force) $$(90,13);\;(5,5);\;(2,3);\;(1,2)$$

I managed to find only the even solution $y=2$ analytically

I did in this way

Solving $x^2 + x + 2- 2^y=0$

discriminant is $1-4(2-2^y)=4\cdot 2^y-7$

It is a perfect square if

$4\cdot 2^y -7=a^2$

that is $4\cdot 2^y-a^2=7$

factoring RHS

$\left(2\cdot 2^{y/2}+a\right)\left(2\cdot 2^{y/2}-a\right)=7$

Which means that $2\cdot 2^{y/2}+a=7$ and $2\cdot 2^{y/2}-a=1$

that is $a = 2\cdot 2^{y/2}-1$ and

$2\cdot 2^{y/2}+ 2\cdot 2^{y/2}-1=7$

$ 4\cdot 2^{y/2}=8\to 2^{y/2}=2\to \color{red}{y=2;\;x=1}$

But I don't know how to find the odd solutions for $y$

Hope this helps